# avoid repeating records in many2many in odoo8

Tags: python, odoo-8

everybody. I dont know how I can only add the record once in the field many2many. for example: I have 2 record, in one I add the record A in m2m. I want in the 2nd record not appear the record A in the options.  Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this :

```
<field name="record_1_ids"/>

<field name="record_2_ids" domain="[('id', 'not in', record_1_ids and record_1_ids[0] and record_1_ids[0][2] or False)]" />
```